# Adding value to the scope outside the controller method

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am wondering how I can add a value to the scope from a function outside the controller. I have a series of functions in my controller file, which I would like to keep it separately outside a controller method, so that it can be accessed by different controllers. When the last function gets the value, I want to add it to the scope. Can anybody give me some input into this issue. Thanks

Comment: may be your looking for angular services???

Comment: have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs

Comment: I tried services. But I am unable to get the function value back to the controller. Since the called function directly don't return any data but another linked function.

Comment: you can chain functions and on final function you can broadcast event and subscribe that event on controller where you want to use this value.Hope you know how to broadcast and subscribe event??

Comment: That sounds interesting. Please let me know if you have some sample code. Thanks

Comment: you can return data in the function inside a service, you must be doing @MACMAN something wrong

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v3xjjy5c/2/ fiddle demo for you

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I can broadcast the value from service and get it from my controller. Thanks for the fiddle.

Comment: you can also use window.localStorage['variable'] = value;

Answer (score 2):

Angular `$scope` is not supposed to be accessed from outside. Use [`service/factory/provider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) to share data between controllers.

Say, define a `factory` with `get/set` functions. `set` the value in some controller and `get` it from somewhere else. `$scope` is not supposed to be passed around.